# How i can i add a split button or list box to the WordPress TinyMCE instance

Tags: tinymce, buttons, split, plugin-tinymce

I have added a custom button to the tinymce to insert my shortcodes, but I have so many and I want to make a splitbutton instead and I can't figure how. Anyone can help. Here's the code that I've used to create the normal button:

in functions.php :

```
/**
Hook into WordPress
*/

add_action('init', 'onehalf_button');  
/**
Create Our Initialization Function
*/

function onehalf_button() {

   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
     return;
   }

   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {
     add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin' );
     add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_button' );
   }

}
/**
Register Button
*/

function register_button( $buttons ) {
 array_push( $buttons, "|", "onehalf" );
 return $buttons;
}
/**
Register TinyMCE Plugin
*/

function add_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
   $plugin_array['onehalf'] = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/tinymce_buttons.js';
   return $plugin_array;
}
```

and in the custom plugin .js

```
// JavaScript Document
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.onehalf', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('onehalf', {
                title : 'One Half Column',
                image : url+'/mylink.png',
                onclick : function() {
                     ed.selection.setContent('[one_half]' + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/one_half]');

                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('onehalf', tinymce.plugins.onehalf);
})();
```

I've found something here http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/listbox_splitbutton.php but can't figure out how to implement it into WP.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be pretty straight-forward, copy the relevant pieces of code from the page you linked to into your existing TinyMCE plugin, update a few strings... done!..

Start with this for your TinyMCE plugin JS and see how you get on..

```
// JavaScript Document
(function() {
    // Creates a new plugin class and a custom listbox
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.onehalf', {
        createControl: function(n, cm) {
            switch (n) {
                case 'onehalf':
                    var mlb = cm.createListBox('onehalf', {
                        title : 'My list box',
                        onselect : function(v) {
                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Value selected:' + v);
                        }
                    });

                    // Add some values to the list box
                    mlb.add('Some item 1', 'val1');
                    mlb.add('some item 2', 'val2');
                    mlb.add('some item 3', 'val3');

                // Return the new listbox instance
                return mlb;

                /*
                case 'onehalf':
                var c = cm.createSplitButton('onehalf', {
                    title : 'My split button',
                    image : 'img/example.gif',
                    onclick : function() {
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Button was clicked.');
                    }
                });

                c.onRenderMenu.add(function(c, m) {
                    m.add({title : 'Some title', 'class' : 'mceMenuItemTitle'}).setDisabled(1);

                    m.add({title : 'Some item 1', onclick : function() {
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Some  item 1 was clicked.');
                    }});

                    m.add({title : 'Some item 2', onclick : function() {
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Some  item 2 was clicked.');
                    }});
                });

                // Return the new splitbutton instance
                return c;
                */
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('onehalf', tinymce.plugins.onehalf);
})();
```

If something doesn't work please report back with as much info as possible, ie. what you tried, what the result was, what did happen, what didn't ... etc..

Comment: You, sir, are gold. It is just what I need. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome... :) Was on that very same page a little while back myself... If you have any problems add them into this question, and drop a comment on this answer(i'll help if i can - having done something similar myself recently).

Answer (score 4):

t31os answer is great. Just a side note: to obtain the path to the image add

```
init : function(ed, url) {
    theurl = url;
},
```

right before `createControl: function...` and now you can use it in

```
var c = cm.createSplitButton('onehalf', {
    title : 'My split button',
    image : theurl + '/theicon.png',
    onclick : function() {
           tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Button was clicked.');
    }
});
```

Assuming your icon is right next to the JavaScript for the TinyMCE plugin.

Comment: Careful - You created a global variable with `theurl`. You should store it as a property of the plugin. For example `tinymce.plugins.onehalf.theurl = url;` - Then to retrieve it, you would use `image : tinymce.plugins.onehalf.theurl + '/theicon.png',`

Comment: Nice addition, i'll leave that absent from my code though, you deserve the rep for the addition.. :)